# Insert Data using ajax on codeigniter

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

I am trying to insert data using ajax in my codeigniter app but every time i click the submit button the whole page is reloads and nothing happens. actually the form submit button is not working in my case. But when i have tried the same code without ajax it can submit the data into database by using action on the form.

My view :

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
  /*submit form via ajax*/
  $("#createGrade").on('click', function (e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $.ajax({
    url: '<?php echo base_url();?>index.php?admin/exam_grade/create',
    data: {
      grade_title: $("#grade_title").val(),
      grade_point: $("#grade_point").val(),
      mark_from: $("#mark_from").val(),
      mark_upto: $("#mark_upto").val(),
      comment: $("#comment").val()
    },
    async: 'true',
    cache: 'false',
    type: 'post',
    success: function (data) {
      //jQuery("#attendence_report_holder").html(response);
      alert("Data successfully added");
    }
  });
});

</script>
```

```html
<form method="post" role="form">
  <!-- start form elements -->
  <div class="form-group">
    <div class="input-group">
      <span class="input-group-addon"><?php echo get_phrase(' grade_title'); ?></span>
      <input type="text" id="grade_title" name="grade_title"  autocomplete="off" class="form-control" placeholder="A+"  required>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <div class="input-group">
      <span class="input-group-addon"><?php echo get_phrase(' grade_point'); ?></span>
      <input type="number" id="grade_point" name="grade_point"  autocomplete="off" class="form-control" placeholder="5"  required>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <div class="input-group">
      <span class="input-group-addon"><?php echo get_phrase(' mark_from'); ?></span>
      <input type="number" id="mark_form" name="mark_from"  autocomplete="off" class="form-control" placeholder="70"  required>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <div class="input-group">
      <span class="input-group-addon"><?php echo get_phrase(' mark_upto'); ?></span>
      <input type="number" id="mark_upto" name="mark_upto"  autocomplete="off" class="form-control" placeholder="100"  required>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <div class="input-group">
      <span class="input-group-addon"><?php echo get_phrase(' comment'); ?></span>
      <textarea class="form-control" id="comment" rows="3" name="comment" placeholder="add comment"></textarea>
    </div>
  </div>

  <!-- end form elements -->
  <div class="col-xs-6 form-group">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success pull-left" id="createGrade"><?php echo get_phrase('submit');?></button>
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-6 form-group">
    <button type="reset" class="btn btn-warning pull-right"><?php echo get_phrase('reset');?></button>
  </div>
</form>
```

and This is my controller:::

```html
function exam_grade($param1 = '', $param2 = '')
{
    if ($this->session->userdata('admin_login') != 1)
    redirect(base_url(), 'refresh');
    if ($param1 == 'create') {
        $data['name']        = $this->input->post('grade_title');
        $data['grade_point'] = $this->input->post('grade_point');
        $data['mark_from']   = $this->input->post('mark_from');
        $data['mark_upto']   = $this->input->post('mark_upto');
        $data['comment']     = $this->input->post('comment');
        $this->db->insert('grade', $data);
        $this->session->set_flashdata('flash_message' , get_phrase('data_added_successfully'));
    }
}
```

Comment: appears you forgot to wrap the click listener  in *`document.ready`* so it is likely running before button exists ... or a script error is being thrown in page and the click handler isn't being activated

Comment: I have modified my ajax function but its also reloads the form after submitting my form. or in the error section it doesn't trigger any error message. Please view my updated ajax function.

Comment: put an alert inside that click handler and see if it fires. You didn't seem to add `document ready`

Comment: Yes i have put the document.ready actually i am using bootstrap modal window for my form view. Please review my ajax function once again. I am new to Javascript and ajax, so need some help to accomplish this issue. by using document.ready it also reloads my page after clicking my submit button.

Comment: I have tried this but its not triggering any alert instead the page is still reloads '$(document).ready(function(){
    $(document).on('click', '#createGrade', function (evt) {
        alert("the submit button is clicked");
    });
  });'

Comment: if the delegated version using `$(document).on('click',` doesn't work I have no idea why...that should definitely work if selector is correct (which it appears to be). Would need to see a demo where this fails

Comment: @charlietfl  I am working on localhost. so i have not any link to show you a demo :( .. Is there any way to show you a demo of  my code

Answer (score 0):

@raduation i have make it working by placed the code at the end of my page or after loading jquery into the page. The alert message is displaying .. but the error message is triggered.  Is my post data has any coding that helps to trigger the error message.

```js
<script>
$("#createGrade").on('click', function (e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $.ajax({
    url: '<?php echo base_url();?>index.php?admin/exam_grade/create',
    data: {
      grade_title: $("#grade_title").val(),
      grade_point: $("#grade_point").val(),
      mark_from: $("#mark_from").val(),
      mark_upto: $("#mark_upto").val(),
      comment: $("#comment").val()
    },
    async: 'true',
    cache: 'false',
    type: 'post',
    success: function (data) {
      //jQuery("#attendence_report_holder").html(response);
      alert("Data successfully added");
    },
    error:function(data){
      alert("error happend");
    }
  });
});
})();  
</script>
```

Answer (score -1):

Remove `type="submit"` from the button.  This attribute causes the button to submit the form, which causes a page reload in the browser.

Comment: `e.preventDefault();` takes care of that issue

Comment: It does not take care of the issue - the submit event will not be cancelled, only the click event itself.  A simple test will confirm this.

Comment: `$(document).ready(function(){
    $(document).on('click', '#createGrade', function (evt) {
      e.preventDefault();
        alert("the submit button is clicked");
    });
  });`
I have tried this one as well but nothing happens and remove by `type="submit"` but non of them working in my case.

Comment: The default is "submit" if the attribute is not specified.  Use type="button".

Comment: when i use type button it actually stop the page reloading :)  but the problem is it does not trigger any message when i click the submit button. any idea regarding the issue @raduation

Comment: Seems to work for me, at least in triggering the event handler.  https://jsfiddle.net/bp00hfm6/  ... are you sure the proper URL is getting requested?

Comment: Yes your jsfiddle is working but the same code is not working inside my program .. I don't know what is happening .. Is this problem is triggered by using bootstrap modal ?? I am using it for my form view.

Comment: Then the code you posted is incomplete and difficult for me to test.  I recommend trying this without bootstrap modal, to see whether the ajax is the issue or the modal.

Comment: @raduation Yes the alert is working please view my answer but the error message is triggered .. is my post data and controller has any code that helps to trigger the error message.